# Why are my comment flags continually getting rejected?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging, flags

A little while ago I asked ([Should I flag comments such as “I agree”, “+1 for x”, or “I changed x in my post”?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6342/should-i-flag-comments-such-as-i-agree-1-for-x-or-i-changed-x-in-my-post)) if certain kinds of comments should be flagged as useless, and got told that I should just flag it if it did not contribute to the question/answer.

This is reinforced by [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2407/47437), which states that comments that are obsolete, wrong, "noisy" (too talkative), rude/insulting, or useless should be flagged.

So I started flagging tons of useless comments all over the place.  I was pretty careful about what I flagged, most of them got accepted, and everything was hunky-dory for a while.

Then my comment flags started getting rejected.  **All** of them.  Here is a sampling (of just the ones that I got the URLs for):

- [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap#comment54361_49109)
- [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap#comment54432_49109)
- [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap#comment220157_49138)
- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration#comment117402_72589)

These comments are **clearly** not useful.  My question is, why are these (and many other) comment flags getting rejected?  Is there an auto-reject trigger that activates if a user flags too many comments at once?  Did I get on the bad side of some moderator?  Did I do something wrong?  What is going on?

Comment: Anyone wondering about the broken links to the comments, I cleaned them up just now. Sorry about that.

Comment: For posts *reasonable to flag*, mods should mark flags helpful [even when not actioning them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160331). It's one thing if flags on borderline-worthless comments don't always result in the comment being deleted. But if one or more moderators are *rejecting* reasonable comment flags (causing them to be listed as *declined* when you click on your number of helpful flags, as shown to you in your profile), that's cause for concern. (Any moderator unfamiliar with this SE-wide policy should read http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/.)

Comment: @EliahKagan We can't mark comment flags helpful without taking an action on the flag, so it's best if you use custom and explain for borderline comment flags.

Comment: @Seth Is this new? I feel pretty sure I've had comment flags marked helpful--many times, I think--where the comment was not deleted or edited.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm not sure. It has been this way since I was elected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok one at a time:

- Is there an auto-reject trigger that activates if a user flags too many comments at once?

  I hope not except for some spammer, but still I hope not.
- Did I get on the bad side of some moderator?

  Maybe... maybe not.. maybe you rock and are awesome. All serious here, as a moderator we really do not have time to get to a point where we are angry or have a problem at somebody. Between real life stuff, Q/A in this site and the amount of mod activity, one would be lucky to get to know at least 10 users.
- Did I do something wrong?

  For what I could see no. You have not done anything wrong...yet ^^
- What is going on?

  Maybe a mod though the opposite or had a mistake. Mods are not robots..yet ^^

If you want (Maybe you already did) when flagging a comment you could add why it should be removed/edited/moved... That way it helps to sort the problem out, from many flags we get everyday. Well at least in my case (And I am the slowest of all moderators, so you can imagine the rest).

Comment: You may want to clarify that the proper way to say why a comment should be removed while flagging it is to use a custom comment flag, by clicking the flag icon by the comment and then clicking *other...*.